# front camera through the app not working but back camera is working fine

Tags: android

what i have to do with my code to find the solution to work the front camera in my application.

device model A 8
android version 4.4.2

please suggest me some solution to solve this issue in my application

Comment: Hi nithya can you tell what you doing it now...so that i can help you accordingly

Comment: @Nithya sri  Upload your code or something, information is not enough

Answer (score 1):

Use default camera in the device and the user can switch between front and back camera. I have done a project with device default camera and worked fine.

This link may help you:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/